# Did Wolfe kill Triphammer?

Tags: plot-explanation, powers

Did Triphammer die in the fight with Wolfe on episode 5 of *Powers* (2015)? I really like him and it would be a shame for him to die like this, he's such a kind soul.

Comment: Well, there are 5 more episodes left in the season. You'll probably just have to wait, at the very least 5 more days for the next one. In any case, according to IMDb, the actor filmed *9 episodes*.

Comment: If IMDB says that, then I would probably NOT have to wait :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Wolfe, when leaving him, said something along the lines of "I could eat you now, but you are basically a robot", I think it's safe to say that Triphammer is still alive.

Comment: Actually I should have done more research, the **POWERS - This Season on... Trailer** shows that Triphammer is questioning Wolfe in the drainer. So he must have survived. I am relieved :)